# multiple hits in loop after the break command

Tags: c#, kinect, nui

I've got a strange problem. I'm creating a NUI for application and I binded some simple gestures to right and left arrow. The problem is when I start application. When I make gesture for the first time my application is hitting 2 times in a row. After that it works 100% as I want. Only the start is the problem.

I'm adding two Joints and timestamp to my history struct which is put into the ArrayList

```
        this._history.Add(new HistoryItem()
            {
                timestamp = timestamp,
                activeHand = hand,
                controlJoint = controlJoint
            }
        );
```

then in foreach loop I'm comparing data

```
if (Math.Abs((hand.Position.X - item.controlJoint.Position.X)) < MainWindow.treshold && Math.Abs((hand.Position.Y - item.controlJoint.Position.Y)) < MainWindow.verticalTreshold)
```

If it hits I instantly break the lopp with

```
break;
```

after that I clear the history ArrayList

```
this._history.Clear();
```

So I don't get it. Why after the start it hits two times in a row ?

// edit

history ArrayList initialization

```
private List<HistoryItem> _history = new List<HistoryItem>(16);
```

in loop

```
foreach (HistoryItem item in this._history)
        {
         if ((hand.Position.X - item.controlJoint.Position.X) < MainWindow.treshold)
                            {
                                float tmp = (hand.Position.X - controlJoint.Position.X);
                                MainWindow.slideNumber++;
                                this._logger.Log("Next slide: " + MainWindow.slideNumber);
                                this._logger.Log(hand.Position.X + " - " + controlJoint.Position.X + " = " + tmp + " | " + MainWindow.treshold);
                                this.startTime = 0;
                                this.gestureStart = false;
                                answerFlag = true;
                                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");
                                break;
                            }
                }
```

Now. As you can see i'm breaking here. So this code shouldn't be invoked second time in a row

How this clears something

// edit 2

I'll also add that to get into this part of code the gestureStart flag need to be set to true. As you can see after getting into the 'if' part here I'm setting it to false. So it is impossible that the code instantly can get to this part

// edit 3 **WORKING WORKAROUND**

I've created kind of workaround. I've added time control. I'm comparing timestamp of invoking the code and timestamp of last gesture recognition. If its too fast ( i meen couple of ms which it impossible to make ) I don't allow to hit an arrow. I'm not sure if it's a perfect solution but it is a working solution

Comment: It is not very easy to follow you, but usually such things happen when something is wrong with initialization code.

Comment: @AndriyBuday its hard to fallow cause the problem is strange and its hard to describe it. If you need more info just say what you need and I'll try to add it. About the initialization. ArrayList are initialized on start of the program: private List<HistoryItem> _history = new List<HistoryItem>(16); nothing else

Comment: You should probably paste a little more code to show the transitions. Also, as the problem is likely to be in the init code, could you summarize what you put in there?

Comment: what do you mean "the application is hitting two times in a row?"

Comment: @OutlawLemur as I wrote. The application after recognizing the gesture is hitting the right arrow command two times in row. Sometimes 3 times in a row after the start of application. When it make a second or further gesture recognition everything works fina. Also as I wrote in edit3 I found a workaround using current timestamp. It helped but I'm not 100% sure that this is the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my problem was the code. Ofc a small bug untracable in the debug. I used one function to analyse a history of frames.

The method was working in 2 modes. I`ve detached that and created 2 diffrent methods, each for each task and now it works great