# application is not working correctly when it is in background

Tags: kinect

I've created NUI for some standard windows application. My problem is that when I start my app and the windows application my app isn`t working correctly. I have there gestures bind to few keys (for example right arrow).

Now when MY application is in foreground everything works ok, but when the windows app is in the foreground and MY app is in the background. key binding does not work.

I'm sure that my app is recognizing gestures cause when I put console with debug I can see that gestures are recognized correctly and proper code fragment is invoked. So why the binding to the key won`t work when the windows app is in full screen mode and my app is working in the background ?

I hope the problem is clear enough

Comment: @OutlawLemur it`s not much to add. It`s a bit a general question. Maybe this will help. I`m binding the arrow this way: System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was connected with my diffrent topic: [multiple hits in loop after the break command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079711/multiple-hits-in-loop-after-the-break-command)

Generaly workaround whitch I've created blocked the arrow hitting. The logging was ok thats why I didn`t notice that. After code rafactoring, splitting functions etc everything works fine